# Is it possible to share internet on a switch connected to a computer?

Tags: switch

The configuration is this: computer no. 1 has two Ethernet ports: one is connected to internet and the other is connected to an unmanaged switch(Netgear GS108).

1. Is it possible for computer no. 1 to "share internet on the switch", so that any computer that connects to the switch can access the internet?
2. Is it possible for computer no.1 to "share internet" with a particular computer, so that anytime it connects to the switch, it can access the internet?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can turn on IP forwarding on a Windows computer.  But it would be better to put the switch in front of the first computer and connect both computers to the switch.